# How to get vertex ids back from graph

Tags: r, igraph

Please consider the following

```
library(igraph)
id <- c("1","2","A","B")
name <- c("02 653245","03 4542342","Peter","Mary")
category <- c("digit","digit","char","char")
from <- c("1","1","2","A","A","B")
to <- c("2","A","A","B","1","2")

nodes <- cbind(id,name,category)
edges <- cbind(from,to)

g <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed=TRUE, vertices=nodes)
```

Now I want to access a specific vertex of the graph using the ids I used to create the graph from the data frame `id <- c("1","2","A","B")`.

Let's say I want to access the third vertex - originally identified with "A". Is there any way to access the vertex with something like

```
V(g)$id == "A"
```

And is there anyway to obtain the `id` from `name`? That is, if I run

```
which(V(g)$name == "Peter")
```

I get `3`. How to get `A` instead?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all, igraph uses the vertex attribute `name` as symbolic ids of vertices. I suggest you add the ids as `name` and use another name for the other attributes, e.g. `realname`.

But often you don't need to know the numeric ids if you are using symbolic names, because all functions accepts (well, they should) symbolic ids as well. E.g. if you want the degree of vertex `Peter`, you can just say `degree(g, "Peter")`.

If you really want the the numeric id, you can do things like these:

```
as.numeric(V(g)["Peter"])
# [1] 3
match("Peter", V(g)$name)
# [1] 3
```

If you want to get to `id` from `name` in your example, you can just index that vector with the result:

```
id[ match("Peter", V(g)$name) ]
```

Comment: Following your example, let's say I know that `V(g)$name` is `Peter`  in my graph and I want to find the corresponding symbolic name `(A)`. If I do `which(V(g)$name == "Peter"` I get back the index (3) not the symbolic name (A). (I updated my question)

Comment: (Also in my example `name` and `id` are different vectors in the generating data frame).

Comment: I see. igraph uses the vertex attributes `name` as symbolic id. You can still use `match` and just index `id` with the result: `id[ match("Peter", V(g)$name) ]`.

Comment: I found for some functions, with or without a 'name' attribute, the computational time differs quite a lot. For example the strength function:

Comment: @yliueagle Then just use the fastest way?

Comment: A simpler but less general solution is to use indexing and `names()`. I.e. `names(V(g)["Peter"])`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's OK to be posting on such an old thread, but it is directly relevant so I'll go ahead. I have tried the above in python3 and it doesn't work. I get an 'invalid syntax' 'syntaxerror' pointing to the $ sign, so I suppose this is the fault. Is this different in python3?

Comment: @21joanna12 This question is in R, not in Python

Comment: Just to point out, the `as.numeric(V(g)["Peter"]` could also be run in a vectorized manner to give you all the ids quickly, i.e. `as.numeric(V(g)[name]`

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be useful. My recommendation is same as of @Gabor Csardi about id as name, and name as real_name.

```
library(igraph)
name <- c("1","2","A","B")
real_name <- c("02 653245","03 4542342","Peter","Mary")
category <- c("digit","digit","char","char")
from <- c("1","1","2","A","A","B")
to <- c("2","A","A","B","1","2")

nodes <- cbind(name,real_name,category)
edges <- cbind(from,to)

g <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed=TRUE, vertices=nodes)

list.vertex.attributes(g)
#Output: [1] "name"      "real_name" "category"
which(V(g)$real_name == "Peter")
#Output: [1] 3
V(g)$name[which(V(g)$real_name == "Peter")]
#Output: [1] "A"
```