# Function to find sub ID's of an ID in a data frame

Tags: r, subset, igraph, tidygraph

I have a data frame that contains two columns, an ID column and a column with sub ID's that are related to the corresponding ID. The sub ID's can again have sub ID's (in this case the previous sub ID is now an ID).

```
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 7), sub_id = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8))

df

# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id sub_id
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1      2
2     1      3
3     2      4
4     2      5
5     3      6
6     7      8
```

I would like to write a function that finds all sub ID's that are related to an ID. It should return a vector with all sub ID's.

```
find_all_sub_ids <- function (data, id) {
data %>% ...
}

find_all_sub_ids(df, id = 1)

[1] 2 3 4 5 6

find_all_sub_ids(df, id = 2)

[1] 4 5

find_all_sub_ids(df, id = 9)

[1] NULL
```

This is very different from everything I have done in R so far and it was hard for me to phrase a good title for this question. So it is possible that with the right phrasing I could have already found an answer by just googling.

My first intuition for solving this was while loops. Since I also do not know how many sublevels there could be the function should continue until all are found. I never used while loops though and don't really know how I could implement them here.

Maybe someone knows a good solution for this problem. Thanks!

Edit: Forgot to assign the tibble to df and to use this argument in the function call.

Comment: Why `find_all_sub_ids(id = 1)` gives you so many numbers if there is only `2,3`?

Comment: with `dplyr` and your tibble called DF you could do `find_all_sub_ids <- function (x) dplyr::filter(DF, id==x) %>% .$sub_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `igraph`:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(d, directed = TRUE)

find_all_subs <- function(g,id){
  #find child nodes, first one being origin
  r <- igraph::subcomponent(g,match(id, V(g)$name),"out")$name
  #remove origin
  as.numeric(r[-1])
}
find_all_subs(g,1)
[1] 2 3 4 5 6

find_all_subs(g,2)
[1] 5 6
```

Comment: After trying it out with my actual data I noticed it does not work properly if I use different ID's. 
```df <- tibble(id = c(10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70), sub_id = c(200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000))``` 
If you look for id = 10 you do not get 200 and 300. r would return 400 but is then NULL because r[-1].

Comment: see my edit, again a id vs name problem, this time with the id input to the function. igraph stays a good solution, but id/name logic has to be under control ;)

Comment: I think you can use `subcomponent(g,toString(id),"out")$name` to fix the problem

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, I tried your suggestion but get an 'invalid vertex name' error. See my edit : a bit trickier. This is however the [suggested way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20220038/13513328) by the creator of the igraph package.

Comment: I think OP wants the results `find_all_subs(g,10)` for `id = 10`, so you can use a character `"10"` as an input

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easiest to formulate this as a graph problem.
Your data.frame describes a directed graph (vertices going from id to sub_id), and you are interested in which nodes are reachable from a certain vertex.

Using [tidygraph](https://tidygraph.data-imaginist.com), this can be achieved as such:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)

df <- tibble(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 7), sub_id = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8))

find_all_sub_ids <- function (id) {
  if (!(id %in% df$id)) {
    return(NULL)
  }

  
  grph <- df %>% 
    as_tbl_graph(directed = TRUE)
  
  id <- which(grph %>% pull(name) == as.character(id))
  
  grph %>% 
    activate(nodes) %>% 
    mutate(reachable = !is.na(bfs_dist(id))) %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    filter(reachable) %>% 
    pull(name) %>% 
    as.numeric()
}
```

We see which nodes are reachable (they have a non-NA distance to your given node), we use `bfs_dist` (see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidygraph/versions/1.2.0/topics/search_graph) for explanation).
This gives

```
> find_all_sub_ids(1)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

> find_all_sub_ids(2)
[1] 2 4 5

> find_all_sub_ids(9)
NULL
```

The advantage of such an approach is that it can search many levels deep without you needing to write a loop explicitly.

**Edit**
There was a bug in my code, `tidygraph::bfs_dist` uses a differend id than I expected. Fixed it now.
On the new example:

```
> find_all_sub_ids(10)
[1]  10 200 300
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works well and does what it should. I learned some new things here thanks to your explanation.

Comment: Also here I noticed that when I test it with my actual data it does not work properly. 
``` df <- tibble(id = c(10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70), sub_id = c(200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000)) ``` 
When I would take another example df and look for id = 10. it returns 400 instead of 10, 200 and 300.

Comment: You are completely right - there was a bug in my code with the ID value (it referred to the row number instead of the value of the ID column). See edit for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using a dataframe. The following works.

```
x= c(1,1,2,2,3,7)
y = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)
df <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))
colnames(df) =c('id', 'sub_id')


find_all_sub_ids <- function (df, id_requested) {
  si <- df[df$id==id_requested,]$sub_id
  return(si)
}
find_all_sub_ids(df,id=2)
[1] 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is the same problem like the answer before. This function does not do what I ask for though. I would like to get all sub ID's of my ID. This one only gives the direct sub ID's and not their sub ID's. Sub ID of 1 is 2 (which has sub ID's 4 and 5) and 3 (which has sub ID 6)